# Missing transaction in newly installed Bither wallet

Tags: synchronization, bither

On [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org) I learned about the [Bither](https://bitcoin.org/en/wallets/desktop/windows/bither/?step=5&platform=windows) wallet.
I installed it, created an HD account, and replenished the wallet sending to the address [19QpMgv2N2hSJNq6Nrkg1rzJ1Fc9s2Pjbf](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/19QpMgv2N2hSJNq6Nrkg1rzJ1Fc9s2Pjbf). As can be seen, the transaction is completed according to blockchain.com, but my wallet is still empty after five days!
The address is correct and I already checked it many times.
I know that my money is there, because it can be checked in the Blockchain system.

How do I withdraw my money from this wallet?
It looks like a scam!
Since https://bitcoin.org advertises this wallet, then they also participate in this.

Comment: When you first install a new wallet, it has to catch up to the latest block. Is your wallet fully caught up? You should be able to find the block syncing status in Advanced Options/Network Monitoring.

Comment: I installed this wallet 5 days ago. After that, I replenished it and now 5 days have passed and nothing has changed. Please tell me the points where to click and what to do, I would appreciate it!
The technical support of the wallet is not responding and I found such a problem on the Internet at other people.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have any personal experience with this wallet, I just saw the description I posted above in one of the issues filed on their GitHub. Maybe you could just go through the options to find something that concerns the status of your synchronization? Maybe your wallet didn't find a node to serve it bloomfilters. I would also suggest that you verify that the address you sent to is part of your wallet.

Answer (score 3):

Updated 2020-04-29

> It turns out to be an issue in TLS version of the windows desktop version. We've released a new version of Bither Desktop to resolve this. Head over to [bither.net](https://bither.net) to download the latest version and it will be all fixed.

I'm the developer of Bither. Sorry for the late response.

No need to worry about your money and Bither is not a scam. Bitcoin.org has a restricted review process to list wallets on it. We can never get access to your private keys, thus your bitcoins are safe in Bither.

Bither is a decentralized [SPV wallet](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Simplified_Payment_Verification). It needs to connect to other bitcoin nodes and sync block data to get all your transaction history. But in some network conditions it would be too hard to connect to any nodes. Bither relies on background processing to help you keep up with the blockchain tip. But mobile devices often have limit on background running time.

In your case, I think you are not syncing to the latest blockchain data. Though I'm not sure what caused this, but there is an easy way to fix it.

Update to the latest version, open Bither, swap to the right page, click `Advanced Options` -> `Reload Transaction Data`. This will download all your transaction history from 3rd party block explorers. And then you should be able to see your bitcoins. Like @Murch mentioned earlier, you can use `Network Monitor` to see if you are catching up with the blockchain tip and what's going on.

If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our support crew listed on [the website](https://bither.net). support@bither.net.

Comment: I wrote to you in the mail, but no one has been responding for a week. I did as you described, but my account is still 0. But the link from the blockchain says the opposite. How do I withdraw my money?

Comment: @Skreppi899 you can try use this command to run Bither `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\JWrapper-Bither\JWrapper-Windows64JRE-00054022688-complete\bin\java.exe -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2  -jar C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\JWrapper-Bither\JWrapper-Bither-00054023177-complete\bither-desktop-1.4.5.jar`. Replace username with your own windows username. A new version including these parameters will be released soon

Comment: @Skreppi899 and you also need to replace 00054022688 with the path on your own system

Comment: Hi @Skreppi899, we've released a new version of Bither desktop to resolve your issue. You can go to bither.net to download the new version now.

Comment: @songchenwen: Thanks for chiming in here! Could you please clarify whether there is a new product by the Bither developers called "Bitpie"? (See other answer.)

Comment: @Murch Yes. Bitpie is our new product. It's not SPV based. So you can get free from all the SPV hassles. But still you control your private keys in your mobile devices, and we can never get access to it.